# can i add meta tags in bottom of page check my code

Tags: html, seo

i have php CMS project and there is header.php file which contain some stylesheets, js and php file and this file is included to all pages.so can't add meta tags in header file. i wanna ask you, can i add `<head>` after `</body>` and before `</html>` in the bottom of page. AND this will good for SEO

```
<?php include_once 'header.php';?>
<!------PAGE CONTENT-------->
<?php include_once 'footer.php';?>//footer have </body>
<head>
    <!--META TITLE-->
    <!--META DESCRIPTION-->
    <!--META KEYWORD-->
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have some logic inside your page content, that is needed in order to build the meta tags (keywords or description), then you could use the Output Control Functions in order to cache everything. (not really recommended)
But in the end he output sequence is set by the HTML5 standard:
https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/
(meta tags inside the head, and the head before the content inside the html tag)

Answer (score -1):

That's absolutely not possible.

Please have a read on the html standard.

https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/

I would recommand to you to start by the learning properly the html before trying to edit a CMS.